# Is there any way to change R# font size?

Tags: resharper, resharper-7.1

is there any way to change the resharper dialogs font size. 
Supposedly it should be a way to do this on VS going to tools-> options-> environment -> fonts and colors -> resharper...
But in my case there is no such option. Am I missing something obvious here?
I tryed uninstalling resharper, repairing resharper, uninstall VS and re install R# but nothing seems to work....(And I tryied in four different machines)
I'm running R#7, VS2012 on a Win8 machine.

Any help will be apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Fonts and Colors -> Show settings for: -> "Environment Font"

You might find that R# uses the "Environment Font" which is the same font for things like Solution Explorer, menu items, etc.  Try changing it and see if it effects resharper.  Of course if they designed it this way, it means your entire VS environment is affected.

Comment: That is what I been doing till now. But at this moment I'm trying a new 11,6 ultrabook and by changing the env font I loose a lot of screen real state.... But truly I hope they didn't designed this way ;). Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ok then... Env font it is! ;) Thanks!